# Calculating average cost with probabilities

Tags: probability

I play a game on PC and have a case I faced before and didn't know if I was calculating it correctly.

Suppose I have an item that costs 1040. I can try enhancing it to a better version that is worth 1480.

I have a 28% chance of succeeding. If it passes, I'll have this item worth 1480, but if it fails, it will downgrade to one version that is worth 960 and I'll have to repair it, costing me plus 20.

I have the option to buy this item directly on market.

So my question is: how do I calculate my average cost of enhancing it, so I know if I should enhance or buy it on market?

My initial thought is:

A (scenario of success): 0.28 * (1480-1040) of profit

B (scenario of failure): 0.72 * (1040-960 + 20) of loss

If A is bigger than B, I should enhance. Otherwise I should buy.

Is it correct?

Thank you very much

Comment: Looks correct to me. So what you calculated was the expected value of the profit from enhancing. What is the price of the item in the market?

Comment: You need to account for the cost of buying directly too, if you plan to do it in the failure case.

Comment: Is 'enhancing' it free?

Comment: The price in the market is the price I mentioned. I do have income tax of 15% if I were to sell on market but I ignored it for now just for letting my question a bit clearer.. haha

Comment: Enhancing costs me 2.. (I left it off the queston to be a bit clearer too).. this cost and the income tax are the only 2 costs I didnt mention :)